# Browse iPhone Photo folders on Mac

Tags: macos

If I plug my iPhone into a Windows computer the photos I believe DCIM folders display as basically a drive. All you do is drag and drop the files you want. This works great!

**How can I do this on macOS, preferably without any additional software?**
Unfortunately on my Mac it forces you to use the Photos application which I do not like. I'm transferring such a large number of files, I don't want airdrop.  AirDrop is to slow and sometimes doesn't work when using differing iOS and MacOS versions.

Right now I hilariously drag the files onto a thumb drive in Windows and then move the thumb drive to my Mac.

Comment: Would you please edit this to include a clear question?

Comment: @Christian so the answer I marked as duplicate doesn't have a response really.

Comment: Sorry, missed that.